# Convert military time to standard time in sql query

Tags: php, mysql, phpactiverecord

I have my php active record with the code like this:

```
$app->get('/dailyReservationReport/request', function ($id=null) {
$status_code = 200;
$resp = array('status'=>'success','message'=>'Query Success','data'=>null);

//$resp['data'] = $id ?  Bus::find($id) : Bus::find_all_by_active('1'); 
$resp['data'] = Ticket::find_by_sql('SELECT routes.line as RouteLine , 
                                            tickets.trip_code as TicketTripCode,
                                            seating_types.code as SeatingTypesCode,
                                            trip_codes.time as TripCodeTime,
                                            tickets.departure_date as DepartureDate
                                     FROM tickets
                                     INNER JOIN routes
                                     ON tickets.route_code = routes.code
                                     INNER JOIN trip_codes
                                     ON tickets.trip_code = trip_codes.bus_class
                                     INNER JOIN seating_types
                                     ON trip_codes.bus_class = seating_types.id
                                     WHERE tickets.departure_date 
                                             BETWEEN "2015-02-04" AND "2015-03-04"');

if(is_object($resp['data'])){
        $resp['data'] = $resp['data']->to_array();
}else{
    $resp['data'] = objToArr($resp['data']);
}

JSONResponse($status_code,$resp);

});
```

And my problem is when I get the result of `tickets.departure_date as DepartureDate` it shows military time. I want to convert it in standard time with am and pm. I tried to add some casting like this `CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(tickets.departure_date AS TIME),100)` but it doesn't work. Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Googling couldn't solve this one?

Comment: I tried googling it now but I can't find the right answer yet.

Comment: Could you give this a try: `select concat(date_format(tickets.departure_date, '%m/%d/%Y'), ' ', time_format(tickets.departure_date,'%r'))  as DepartureDate from tickets`? If the date format is not correct, have a look at [MySQL's date functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)